# Windows Insider doesn't get updates

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, windows-insider

I "enrolled" to windows insider program for more than a year, and I do not get updates, I bothered me but I never got to it.
I installed the windows insider iso to get updates to `Version Dev (OS Build 21354.1)` (as seen in winver)

[image]

but since then, no updates, when I try to check for updates, it runs for a few seconds and then it says `You're up to date`.
So what I want is to get the updates as I should.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Open Start, Settings, Update and on the left side, scroll down to Windows Insider Program.  Check that the Insider Account is correct.

Comment: It is correct yes, the same account I used to download the insider ISOs.

Comment: Un-enroll from Windows Insider, restart the machine, enroll again and see if it updates.

Comment: I did that, and nothing changed. For some reason, and it shown in the screenshot above, I can't pick the insider setting as it is grayed out.

Comment: Short of rebuilding your machine I do not know. My own insider machine is updating fine.